# C# webbrowser out of memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPd3w.png)

Any one seen this before in a C# webbrowser form.

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot of your error, please include the error **as text** as indicated in [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182) and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*WebBrowser* control in *WinForms* is known for leaking memory. As a solution you can automatically refresh the page from time to time (if that is acceptable for your app) as it frees up consumed resources. Or you can search for alternative workarounds here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webbrowser%20leak), as this problem is well-known and has been thoroughly discussed multiple times.